# D3 .append() with variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I have:

```
var parent = d3.select('g.someElement');
```

I'm looking to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
function addContent(content) {
    // content is a D3Selection or SVGElement
    parent.append(content);
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way of appending already-defined SVGElements using D3 without having to unravel their tag name and other properties to be able to do it according to how [`selection.append()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append) is specified. Basically, a lot like how `.appendChild()` works in vanilla JS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the documentation you've linked to, the argument to `.append()` can be a function that returns the DOM element to be appended. Quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uzV5b/):

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = "foo";

d3.select("body").append(function() { return element; });
```

The argument to `.append()` really has to be a function, you can't just pass `element` to it.

Comment: and there it is `The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append.` For some reason I blanked or misunderstood this. just not used to how D3 does things yet. Thank you so much for clarifying and demoing! :)